# looser throw specifier for virtual function : GCC 4.9 complains but MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11

I have original C++ 11 code which was developed for Windows and is able to be compiled by MSVC :

```
 class Base
{
    virtual void myFunc() throw (std::runtime_error) = 0;
};

class D1 : public Base
{
    void myFunc() throw(std::runtime_error) override
    { //
        throw std::runtime_error("This method is not supported in this class so we throw exeception");
    }
};

class D2 : public D1
{
    void myFunc() override
    {
        //real implementation here
    }
};
```

The code is ported to Linux and compiled with GCC 4.9 I got error

> looser throw specifier for 'virtual void D2::myFunc()'

Adding **'throw()'** to **D2::MyFunc** the code is able to be compiled but it is not the expected property for MyFunc.
Is there any way to make this work for GCC ?

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve]?

Comment: exception specifications are to be avoided, cpp core guidelines E.30  : "Exception specifications make error handling brittle, impose a run-time cost, and have been removed from the C++ standard."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc is right; a virtual function in a derived class cannot have a looser exception specifier than the function being overrode in the base class. The reason is pretty clear: if this was allowed, the caller may invoke the overriding function through a base class pointer, thus getting a function doesn't respect the exception-contract of the static type through which it is invoked.

On MSVC this happens to work just because its support for exception specifiers is extremely reduced - it actually parses only `throw()`, all the other exception specifiers are just ignored.

Now, given that exception specifiers other than `throw()` (AKA `nothrow`):

- are ignored in MSVC
- are being deprecated from the standard anyway
- are widely regarded as a mistake, as they buy you pretty much zero compile-time safety - they essentially boil down to wrapping all the annotated functions with a big `try` and calling `std::unexpected` if anything unexpected is thrown -, and even on Java-style checked exceptions it's widely debated if the trouble is actually worth it;

you should probably drop them altogether and never look back.

Comment: Re: "all other exception specifiers are just ignored" -- the marketing spin that Microsoft gave for this was that "exception specifiers are implemented syntactically but not semantically".